# Can I just run tor and obsfproxy on windows platform without having to start tor browser

Tags: configuration, windows

Does anyone know how to start `tor.exe` and `obsf4proxy.exe` on WIN32 platform without having to launch Tor browser?

For instance in order to use a 3389 client to access the 3389 server by tor, I must first start the Tor browser, and in this way `tor.exe` and `obsf4proxy` will run in background.

Comment: since I don't need Tor browser, how can I make it?

Comment: In Windows you can run executables from the `cmd` prompt by typing the name (and path) of the executable. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939897/how-do-you-run-executable-files-on-windows-7-using-the-command-prompt) for more details.

Comment: yes, I know how to run an executable from the cmd prompt, but what i don't know is that i have no idea about the needed input parameters or file for obsf4proxy and obsfproxy to start from cmd line. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the [usage](https://github.com/kheops2713/telecomix-openvpn/tree/master/Windows) for `obfsproxy` looks like:

```
obfsproxy [obfsproxy_args] protocol_name [protocol_args] protocol_options protocol_name
```

So, as an example:

```
obfsproxy obfs2 socks 127.0.0.1:5050
```

Other [options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/obfsproxy.1.html) for `protocol_name` are: `managed`, `dummy`, `b64`, `obfs2` or `obfs3`

You can run `obfsproxy` by specifying something like:

```
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec Path\To\obfs4proxy
```

in the `torrc` file

Comment: Hi, Ron, thanks a lot. I can start obfsproxy now without Tor browser, but I still have a problem, that is in my Win7 program manger, there is a obfs4proxy.exe running when I start Tor browser, what is it? does it has any relation to obfsproxy.exe? As a matter of fact, I just want to run both tor and obfsproxy without Tor browser, how can I make it?

Comment: @Mike Yes, if you run TBB, it runs obfsproxy.exe in the background. If you select any other obfsproxys while setting up bridges in TBB (for eg: `obfs4`) it will run obfs4proxy.exe in the background. You can run obfsproxy by specifying something like `ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec Path\To\obfs4proxy` in the `torrc` file.

Comment: ok, i have deleted this one!

Comment: I've checked it!