# How can I start obfs4proxy.exe without starting Tor Browser?

Tags: configuration, windows, obfsproxy, obfs4

Under WIN7 platform, when I start tor browser, there is a job running in taskmanager named `obfs4proxy.exe.

How can i start it through command-line since I don't need tor browser?

By the way, I can run `tor.exe` from command-line, so now I need `obfsproxy.exe` to run, but when I run it in cmd line, it always says:

> obfs4proxy - must be run as a managed transport.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I have solved this problem. under win7, absolute path must be used for obfs4proxy plugin  in file of torrc-default.

Comment: May I suggest you move the above comment to the answer section and accept it as the answer? Or if you think this is a part of your [previous post](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8610/can-i-just-run-tor-and-obsfproxy-on-windows-platform-without-having-to-start-tor/8613?noredirect=1#comment8337_8613) you may also delete this one. ;)

Comment: good suggestion, I've moved it. :)

Comment: hi Ron, I have finished the other one, but the text format doesn't look good

Comment: ok, i have upvoted your answer, did you see it? :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem. Under Windows 7, the absolute path must be used for the obfs4proxy configuration in torrc-default; the relative path for obfs4proxy plugin doesn't work!

```
## obfs4proxy configuration
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3,obfs4,scramblesuit exec E:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\obfs4proxy
```