# How to use obfs4proxy.exe merely in a console?

Tags: configuration, windows, obfsproxy, obfs4, obfs4proxy

I'm trying to use obfs4proxy compiled from [Yawning/obfs4](https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4), but when I run it in the console, it says

> [ERROR]: obfs4proxy.exe - must be run as a managed transport

I have seen [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/how-can-i-start-obfs4proxy-exe-without-starting-tor-browser). However, I don't need Tor at all, what I want is to use obfs4proxy together with openvpn. Actually, after I install Tor browser and specify the absolute path of obfs4proxy in `torrc` and `torrc-default` file, the error remains.

I wonder if there is a way to just use obfs4proxy in the command line without even installing Tor browser. Do I have to rewrite the code to achieve it?

Thanks.
Tgn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program that wants to connect to obfsproxy must first
speak the Socks4 protocol with obfsproxy. obfsproxy also has to be started with the right Tor pluggable transport enviroment variables.
There is this project:

```
github.com/twisteroidambassador/pluggabletransportadapter
```

that handles Socks4 startup protocol and starting obfsproxy with the right enviroment variables.